# How can I get login status in android app using facebook account?

Tags: android, facebook, connection, facebook-login

I am creating an android application and I want to allow users to login using their facebook account.
what are the steps to follow it ??
what are the tools or the plugins.
Anyone can help me ?? Can anyone give me some steps or tutorials to follow it to accomplish this task? Any article or website that it will help me with my problem ???

I read on facebook developer site but I didn't get what I have to download (Facebook sdk). I didn't know how to build a connection between android and facebook. If anyone helps me I will appreciate that.

Comment: download facebook android sdk!

Answer (score 4):

I used Facebook SDK 4.0.1

```
private void facebookPost() {
    //check login
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if (accessToken == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>" + "Signed Out");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, ">>>" + "Signed In");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Get Started with Facebook SDK tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/).

Comment: There is not much help you can get if you refuse to read the official Facebook tutorial on how to login with Facebook into your app.

Answer (score 0):

If a user was logged in your app, then this should work.

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
Profile.fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
```

I tried and it worked for me. Then the profile wont be null.